# Single line of text field validation in Sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, event-receivers, jquery-ui

I have single line of text field in a Sharepoint 2010 list. I need to validate the particular field. The user will enter the number by starting with I or F. How do I validate the field if the user does not enter the number starting with I or F?

For e.g., (the user will enter I1900 or F9999), but if the users enters without I or F(such as only number 9999) how do I validate this field?

Answer (score 1):

`=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("F";Title));ISNUMBER(FIND("I";Title)))`,
Title - your field

Answer (score 1):

When creating the column, expand the "Column Validation" section and you should see a text box where you can enter a formula.

To test if the first character of a column called "ToValidate" is I or F use:

```
=OR(LEFT(ToValidate,1)="I",LEFT(ToValidate,1)="F")
```

The syntax is basically Excel so you might want to test any other formulas in that first.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a jQuery / JavaScript block on the new/ edit page where you can validate the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use InfoPath, you can do that InfoPath form rules with adding new custom pattern like this:

```
I?F?\d\d\d\d
```